# Clean way to check which list, out of many, a variable is in

Tags: python, list, loops, contains

I want to check in which list the variable `bases` is in, out of 20+ lists. My current solution works, but it's clumsy and messy:

```
bases = "aau"    

ala = ["gca","gcu","gcg","gcc"]
arg = ["agg","aga","cgg","cga","cgc","cgu"]
asn = ["aau","aac"]
# etc - tons of arrays

if bases in ala:
    return "Alanin"
if bases in arg:
    return "Arginin"
if bases in asn:
    return "Asparagin"
# etc - tons of checks
```

In total, with all of the lists and all of the checks, this function is 69 lines. How can I clean this up?

Comment: this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ 
don't ask us to "clean-up" your exsiting, working code

Comment: @Unlockedluca This issue can hardly be specific to me. I could have submitted this question without the example code, wouldn't change a dime. Pretty sure it does belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary that "maps" the name to the lists you defined. Then you could simply iterate over that dictionary:

```
bases = "aau"

dct = {"Alanin": ["gca","gcu","gcg","gcc"],
       "Arginin": ["agg","aga","cgg","cga","cgc","cgu"],
       "Asparagin": ["aau","aac"]}

for name, lst in dct.items():
    if bases in lst:
        return name
```